# Shell sript - Fetch data from Hive table to text file

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive

I'm modifying a shell script and I'm not that familiar with scripting.

I'm able to pull my data from hive table and put in txt file, but the data starts on the first line that I already have pre-typed with the column headers.

How can I get the data to load on the 2nd line onwards?

```
temp_pull()
{
hadoop fs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/test_database.db/$1/* >> $2
}

temp_pull hive_table sample_txt_file.txt
```

example .txt file :

```
col1    col2    col3
```

after calling temp_pull():

```
col1    col2    col3    hivedataRow1    hivedataRow1    hivedataRow1
hivedataRow2    hivedataRow2    hivedataRow3
```

Comment: could you please give the content of `fetch` script?

Comment: just added  command.....

Comment: Which version of `Hadoop` and `hive` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 temp_pull()
  {
  hadoop fs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/test_database.db/$1/*  | tail -n +2 >> $2
  }

  temp_pull srclist sample_txt_file.txt
```

other solution.

```
 temp_pull()
 {
   hive -e 'select * from '$1'' | tail -n +2  > $2
  }

  temp_pull stud_02 sample_txt_file1.txt
```

Adjust it for your need.

Comment: Nah, this still has the first row of data on the first line where my headers are.....

Comment: try with   tail -n  +3

Comment: do you have the  col names and data in the single line like mentioned above..col1    col2    col3    hivedataRow1    hivedataRow1    hivedataRow1